# How to convert custom string to Valid Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am getting a `string` as `10 Apr, 2014 - 09:27` and I want it to compare with the current `DateTime` to see if its lower or above.

The above gives an error as `Not recognized as Valid  DateTime`.

How can I convert this properly?

Do I need to format the date first to some format etc?

Comment: Custom format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`(if the format can be invalid).

This works with your sample:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10 Apr, 2014 - 09:27", "dd MMM, yyyy - HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'm using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure that it works with english month names even if the current culture is different. You need to change `HH` to `hh` if the hours aren't in 24h format.

To compare with the current time use `DateTime.Now`:

```
if(dt > DateTime.Now)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function and give it the [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your are expecting it to be in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to accomplish what you are asking for:

[How to compare DateTime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059497/how-to-compare-datetime-in-c)

Code Snippet (from the link supplied):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
// The example displays the following output:
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```

Hope that helps.