# How to compare the date entered by datetimepicker and current date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have datetimepicker tool that is used for employee birth date entry and I want to check if the user forget to enter the valid birth date and left the datetimepicker on the current date ,so he'll get an alert message.
I've tried to write this code in ValueChanged event but it didn't worked as I wished ... any help

```
if (empRegBdatePicker.Value == DateTime.Today)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid birth date of an employee");
                empRegBdatePicker.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare DateTime in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059497/how-to-compare-datetime-in-c)

Comment: I think we need more information. Does the debugger hit the code above? What is the value of `empRegBdatePicker.Value`? In what way did it not work?

Comment: Do not write it in the ValueChanged event, if the user forgets to input their date of birth the value won't change so the event won't fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check just date, you can try this:

```
if(empRegBdatePicker.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //birthdate is today
}
```

Comment: I'v used your condition in the Validating event and it's perfectly did what I wanted from my question.. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply write

```
if(empRegBdatePicker < Today)
{
    //birthdate is in past
}
```

Also, perform this validation before any save operations instead of some value changed events.

Comment: where should I write this condition?

Comment: You should check that before any "saves" to databases so it validates the rule. With field change events, user can skip (does nothing) and can still manages to get away