# How to get a set number of rows after ordering the records using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using ASP.NET Core with an EF Model. I would like to display a number of rows by Date and then by Time, but I only want 5 records. What am concerned with is it actually ordering all the rows first before taking the 5 records or is it taking the 5 rows from the table and then ordering them. What I need is the former, them to be ordered, than take the 5 records from that already ordered list in linq.

I have tried:

```
Model.Meetings.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time).Take(5)
```

and also,

```
Model.Meetings.Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Date.ThenBy(x => x.Time)
```

The first one doesn't seem to display or actually does not return anything.

The second one works and shows 5 records, but what 5 records?

```
@foreach (var meeting in Model.Meetings.Take(5).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time))
{
    @if (meeting.Date > DateTime.Today)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@meeting.Name</td>
            <td>@meeting.Date</td>
            <td>@meeting.Time</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I expect to get 5 records to display in order by Date then by Time, but order the records first before displaying them.

Here is example data set:

Id  Date    Day IsActive    Location    ThisEventId Time

1   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   2   09:15:00.0000000

2   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   3   09:00:00.0000000

3   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   4   09:30:00.0000000

4   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   5   10:30:00.0000000

5   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   6   11:00:00.0000000

6   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   7   11:30:00.0000000

7   2019-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 Friday  1   On-Campus   8   13:00:00.0000000

8   2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000 Thursday    1   On-Campus   9   08:45:00.0000000

9   2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000 Thursday    1   On-Campus   10  09:00:00.0000000

10  2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000 Thursday    1   On-Campus   11  09:30:00.0000000

Comment: From what I can tell, you want the first query. The second will take 5 items from `Meetings` and then order them. The first will order them and take the first 5. Can you post an example data set of `Model.Meetings`?

Comment: that might work
Model.Meetings.OrderBy(x => new {x.Date, x.Time}).Take(5)

Comment: The first one should be working as you want, but since you're ordering by `Date`, the oldest will appear first, and based on the results you're seeing it's likely that the top `5` oldest results do not have a `Date` that's greater than `Today`. Perhaps you should use `OrderByDescending` instead, or change your `if` condition? To verify, try commenting out the `if` condition and see what you get.

Comment: I added an example of the data. Hope that helps!

Comment: @PowerMouse Was not able to get that code to work, says it needs at least IComparable.

Comment: @Rufus Yeah, turns out my if statement was causing the problem, I will try OrderByDescending instead.

Comment: @Juan, sorry, i messed up with group by. try DateDescending, since you are looking for latest days:
 .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).ThenBy(o=> o.Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** See end of post for updated answer after clarification by OP in comments below.

I believe the comment by @RufusL is correct that you want to use `OrderByDescending`. To provide a solution for this question, see the code below. This will order first by date and then by time, taking the first 5 items.

```
@{ var meetings = Model.Meetings.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x => x.Time).Take(5) }
@foreach (var meeting in meetings) {
    @if (meeting.Date > DateTime.Today) {
        <tr>
            <td>@meeting.Name</td>
            <td>@meeting.Date</td>
            <td>@meeting.Time</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

---

***EDIT:***

To get the dates that are in the future, simply using `>` does not work. You will want to use the `.CompareTo` method. The first step is to filter by times in the future accomplished by the expression below. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059497/how-to-compare-datetime-in-c) address comparing `DateTime` in C#. See also [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) for the `.CompareTo` method.

```
meetings.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) > 0)
```

Then `OrderBy` will sort them with the closest date to today, so the whole expression becomes

```
meetings.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time)
```

A full example is below, where the `List<DateTime>` represents your `Model.Meetings`.

```
class Meeting {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}

List<Meeting> allMeetings = new List<Meeting>() {
    new Meeting{ Name = "1", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 7), Time = new TimeSpan(9, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "2", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 17), Time = new TimeSpan(9, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "3", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 17), Time = new TimeSpan(11, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "4", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 11), Time = new TimeSpan(11, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "5", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 12), Time = new TimeSpan(11, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "6", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 13), Time = new TimeSpan(11, 15, 00) },
    new Meeting{ Name = "7", Date = new DateTime(2019, 07, 14), Time = new TimeSpan(11, 15, 00) },
};

IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings = allMeetings.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time);
foreach (Meeting meeting in meetings) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{meeting.Name}\t{meeting.Date}\t{meeting.Time}");
}
```

Since today is July 11th, the output I receive is below, which is in the desired order.

> 5       7/12/2019 12:00:00 AM   11:15:00
>
> 6       7/13/2019 12:00:00 AM   11:15:00
>
> 7       7/14/2019 12:00:00 AM   11:15:00
>
> 2       7/17/2019 12:00:00 AM   09:15:00
>
> 3       7/17/2019 12:00:00 AM   11:15:00

Comment: This seems to work better, but is there way I can reorder those results so that the closest date to today shows first?

Comment: @Juan to clarify, you want only the dates that are in the future, starting with those closest to today?

Comment: I getting much later dates like 9/16 is why, when 7/19 is actually closer to today but greater than today.

Comment: Correct, starting with those closest to today and in the future

Comment: @Juan see my updated answer, which should solve your issue. Adding `.Take(5)` will work the same on this collection so I did not include that in my updated solution.

Comment: I see, I have Time in a separate column, how would I include that? The same thing just with CompareTo for time?

Comment: @Juan Yes, that should work. Or my recommendation would be to combine date and time columns into a single column using `DateTime`.

Comment: Something like this?

`Model.meetings.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time)`

Comment: I kinda stuck with the Time column being separate due to my requirements.

Comment: @Juan What data type are you using for the `Date` and `Time` columns?

Comment: My final result that works even with the take(5) method: 
`Model.Meetings.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Time).Take(5)`

Thank you so much @ivcubr, I will have to learn more about CompareTo, without that I don't think was able to figure it out.

Comment: I am using DateTime and TimeSpan, for the Date and Time columns

Comment: @Juan I have updated my answer to reflect keeping the `Date` and `Time` columns separate. Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.